# Multiple lines in a box which have ellipsis and vertical-align middle

Tags: html, css

I have containers which have dynamic content and multiple lines of text. I want to show ellipsis (...) if the text does not fit into the container. Also it should be vertically aligned middle.

I created a Codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewnxG with this HTML:

```
<div class="vertically-centered">vertically centered with</div>
<div class="vertically-centered">vertically centered with hello</div>
<div class="vertically-centered">one line</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.vertically-centered {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 6rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.vertically-centered:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In IE11 and Firefox the ellipsis "..." are missing, that is okay to me. In Safari and Chrome it works.

You see, that the first `div` does not work, the text is cut off. The second and third `div` works. So my solution is dependent on the text length. How can I solve this problem without using JavaScript?

Comment: can i change structure? or apply this structure only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check this simple solution *with no additional markup:*

```css
.vertically-centered {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: flex;  /* enables centering for modern non-webkit browsers */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around; /* centers for modern non-webkit browsers */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center; /* centers in -webkit-box automagically! */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertically-centered">vertically centered with</div>
<div class="vertically-centered">vertically centered with hello</div>
<div class="vertically-centered">one line</div>
```

You can also see this solution in action in the [edited CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dcgfe).

**How it works:** your original code is already using Flexbox layout for WebKit-based browsers (in fact, it's outdated 2009 syntax of Flexbox, but, unfortunately, `-webkit-line-clamp` doesn't work with new implementations). Flexbox has its own mechanism for vertical centering. All you need to get the desired behavior in WebKit-based browsers is to remove the `:after` pseudo-element and to add instead the following line of code to `.vertically-centered`:

```
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
```

For other modern browsers, like Firefox 22+ and IE11+, the same layout (except the ellipsis, but you said it's OK) can be achieved by using the new version of Flexbox:

```
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-around;
```

This must be place above `display: -webkit-box` in the code, so Webkit-browsers will still be able to apply `-webkit-line-clamp`.

You can also make it work in IE10 by adding its prefixed version of Flexbox (2011 transitional syntax):

```
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   -ms-flex-direction: column;
   -ms-flex-pack: center;
```

The pen with IE10 support is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/otHdm

The `:after` vertical centering approach didn't work for you in first 'cell' for the following reason: for ilnine-level CSS boxes (like usual text, inline blocks, images etc.) `vertical-align` adjusts the baselines of all such boxes that form a *line box* (see [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)). The height of the line box is computed so that all inline-level boxes in the line fit into it, so the height of the line box can't be less than the height of the tallest inline-level box in it. So your `:after` inline block, which gets 100% of the container height, becomes the tallest element in the *last* line of your block, and because of `vertical-align: middle` the baseline of the *text* in that last line is moved to meet the vertical middle of the text with the middle of this tall inline-block. This is OK when there is only one lime (it's the typical use case for such centering) and when the last line is hidden with `overflow`, but not OK when it's visible).

Comment: This is one hell of an explanation. Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Looks like a very well reasoned answer, unfortunately 7 years later it's not working in Chrome or Edge, any suggestions?

Comment: @Shaun thanks for pointing this out, it really looks like the support of old Flexbox is broken in Chromiums now and `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` doesn't work well together with `-webkit-box-pack: center`. The only solution I see is using and extra wrapper and setting modern Flexbox properties on the outer wrapper and old "-webkit-box-*" properties (except `-webkit-box-pack` which becomes redundant) on the inner one.

Answer (score 7):

here you can find a simplified solution:

```
.vertically-centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

.vertically-centered p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 106px; /* set max-height for ie */
}
```

for a markup like this:

```
<div class="vertically-centered"><p>vertically centered with</p></div>
<div class="vertically-centered"><p>vertically centered with hello</p></div>
<div class="vertically-centered"><p>one line</p></div>
```

an example: http://codepen.io/srekoble/pen/pHgjf

As you will see you could wrap your text inside a p tag so you can apply the truncate method to   `p` tag and the vertical align method to `div` tag

Comment: Your solution does not work with IE11. The text ``hello`` is not truncated and overlap the second box.

Comment: @Tim you could add a `max-height` to fix this issue in ie11 (strange indeed) see the updated answer

Comment: In Safari and Chrome the "one line" is vertically centered. In IE it is not really centered, it is a bit more in direction to top.

Comment: @Tim removing height seems to fix this issue feel free to have a look

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable but will require some changes to the markup.

- Add extra `div`s around the text
- Add `.vertically-centered div` selector with the following rules:

  - `display: inline-block;` as a fallback for non webkit browsers, required for vertical alignment
  - `display: -webkit-inline-box;` for webkit browsers
  - `max-height: 100%;` to ensure the div is only the a high as the text if it is smaller than the container and as high as the container if it grows bigger than it
  - `vertical-align: middle;` to ensure the div is in the middle of the container
- Move the rules responsible for the ellipses from `.vertically-centered` to `.vertically-centered div`

**Why is the extra div required?**

The text on its own is inline so only the last line is vertically aligned to the pseudo element `:after`. So:

- The first example looks wrong because the "centered with" line is being vertically aligned to the middle of the pseudo element.
- The second example looks ok because the hidden "hello" is being vertically aligned, the other lines fit the box nicely anyway.
- The third example is the only one actually being vertically aligned in the middle using this method.

To clearly see this in action change `.vertically-centered:after` to `.vertically-centered:before`, you will see that now the first line "vertically" is in the middle.

Adding the extra container allows for its entire text contents to be vertically aligned rather than just one line.

**Code Pen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/htbxA

```css
.vertically-centered {
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 6rem;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        width: 300px;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .vertically-centered:after {
        content: "";
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .vertically-centered div {
        display: inline-block;
        display: -webkit-inline-box;
        max-height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="vertically-centered"><div>vertically centered with</div></div>
    <div class="vertically-centered"><div>vertically centered with hello</div></div>
    <div class="vertically-centered"><div>one line</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed your css a bit. I added some padding to the .vertically-centered div and set the width of the .vertically-centered:after div and presto! i believe the problem was that there was no width defined in .vertically-centered:after div. here is my solution

```
 .vertically-centered {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;


}

.vertically-centered:after {
    content: "";
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the text inside the divs inside `<p></p>` and add this:

```
.vertically-centered p {
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top:50%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Then it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible if you want this to work in Internet Exporer.

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) is quite a few examples that work in IE:

- Fade Out Way (CSS!)
- Clamp.js Way (javascript)
- TextOverflowClamp.js Way (javascript)

Personally i use http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/